# Use a nullable function property in an Android View instead of defining a listener Interface?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, higher-order-functions

In Android, whenever we want to have a View like a custom Button subclass call out to a consumer that's using it in a layout, the normal pattern that I've seen used is to define a `Listener` interface, define methods on the interface that are to be implemented, and then have a listener property in the custom View subclass that will call them at appropriate times. This works well enough but sometimes I feel that this can get unwieldy and less direct, at times - especially when I just want a single method and I know there's not going to be a future addition.
I've been switching to Kotlin recently and I've been wondering if it makes sense to simply have a direct function var declared in the View subclass, as `Optional` with a `null` default value, something like this:

```Kotlin
class SuperAmazingButton: ImageButton{
    var customAction: (()->Unit)? = null
}
```

When we need to call customAction we can do it in a simple one liner like this along with the safe null check:

```Kotlin
customAction?.invoke()
```

What I'd like to know is if there are any downsides to this approach? Will the android `Context` that is holding on to the View somehow get leaked when the `Activity` or `Fragment` gets dismissed? Are there any other problems that can occur? I mean this looks so simple, easy and straightforward without requiring any new files - it's almost too good to be true!

Comment: I think the problem with this is not what you think. When the receiving class uses the customAction it won't callback to the activity or fragment, whatever the method does it will be executed and thats it. Passing a function is useful is you need someone else define something on behalf of that class, like with the filter, the filter predicate is a function pass as an argument https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html

Comment: @cutiko - I don't understand your issue with this. The goal is to execute some code. Who cares where the code is? I can still pass in a function that updates my activity. Plus the passed function could be set as a method reference.

Comment: I use `typealias XxxListener = (data: Data) -> Unit` to give a meaningful name to the listener type, and then declare the param as `xxxListener: XxxListener`. For fragments, if the activity is the listener, you're forced back to using interfaces.

Comment: Found a proandroiddev.com article which seems to suggest that using higher order functions is a Good Idea. :-) https://proandroiddev.com/kotlin-functions-an-alternative-to-interfaces-7cfb3c435900